# Getline() combined with cin.ignore() is not storing variable? (Bug)

Tags: c++

I don't think this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021224/why-does-the-program-not-stop-for-the-input). Even though it is caused by the same thing, it is a different manifestation of the problem.

---

The terminal output when I run this program looks like this (my input is `1` and `Rock Lee` followed by `enter`):

> Enter a number: `1`
>
> Enter your name: `Rock Lee`
>
> Name is blank.

However, the name shouldn't be blank. Why is the name variable `""`? How do I fix this bug? Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    
    int num;
 
    string name;
    
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, name, '\n');
    
    cin.ignore (1000, '\n');
    
    if (name == "")
    {
        cout << "Name is blank.";
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Also, please note that I want to use Getline() in the solution, and I want to be able to read an entire line (so the name can be anything, not just first and last name).

When I tried commenting out `cin.ignore(1000, '\n');`, it gave this output which is also incorrect:

> Enter a number: `1`
>
> Enter your name: Name is blank.

It doesn't even give me a chance to type in my name. How do I fix this?

Comment: Just use getline(cin, name);

Comment: @NafeeurRahman I just tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: You need to use `ignore` *before* you call `getline`

Comment: use getchar() after cin>>num;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the program not stop for the input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021224/why-does-the-program-not-stop-for-the-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> num` reads until it sees whitespace, but it doesn't discard the whitespace, so it leaves `'\n'` in the input.  Your call to `getline` sees it and immediately returns, filling `name` with an empty string.  You need to call `cin.ignore` before `getline` to ignore the `'\n'` that `cin::operator>>` left laying around.